# Raspberry pi camera module 3 works only on libcamera

Tags: python, pi-3b+, camera, raspicam, picamera

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3b+ and Camera module v3. After days of troubleshooting, I got the camera to spit out images on the `libcamera` CLI. But, I can't create a `picamera.PiCamera` object in Python. Here's my error:

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from picamera import PiCamera
>>> camera = PiCamera()
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 456, in _init_camera
    self._camera = mo.MMALCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2279, in __init__
    super(MMALCamera, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 631, in __init__
    mmal_check(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.ril.camera': Out of memory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 431, in __init__
    self._init_camera(camera_num, stereo_mode, stereo_decimate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 459, in _init_camera
    raise PiCameraError(
picamera.exc.PiCameraError: Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.
```

Using `libcamera`, I don't get any errors. But, when I try creating a `PiCamera` object, it fails, giving the above error. Please help!

Here's my specs:

- Raspberry pi 3b+
- Raspberry Camera Module 3

Comment: Ooh. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old camera stack with Picamera will not be updated for the new v3 camera.
You will have to swap to the Picamera2 modules.

Comment: I'm fairly new to RPi. Can you please tell me how I'm supposed to do that?

Comment: Also, I get `cannot import name PiCamera2 from picamera2` when I try to use `PiCamera2`.

Comment: Great, now I get `Exception: EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import missing`

Comment: TYSM, it works now!

Comment: @N3RDIUM FYI: there is a lot if documentation available at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html, including a doc fot picamera2